# php and interspire grab information from dropshipper

Tags: php, curl, interspire-shopping-cart

I need to grab information from my dropshipper's site. The only thing I really need to grab is the inventory count. What would be the best technique for doing this with php? Should I use cURL? If so, can you please give me some example code of how to do it?

P.S. I am using interspire shopping cart too

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to answer without knowing what your dropshipper allows. Mine gave me a detailed user guide with several ways to get data from their servers (cURL, Ruby, PHP, Perl, etc. all with example code).

The way I handled real time stock levels was to build code from one of their examples and using XML-RPC grab the stock levels from the supplier when a customer navigates to the individual product pages. The response from the supplier's server is just the stock number for that product (based on the SKU). My code then inserts that stock level into the prodcurrentinv field in the database for that particular product. This all happens in a split second before the page loads fully (before the stock level display on the page). I added it as a function in class.product.php.

Because I don't really know PHP, I wasn't able to get this to work with more than one SKU at a time (for use in the shopping cart and on the category product listing pages). I'm hiring a programmer for that.

But it's really important to know what type of interaction your supplier allows and it's hard to answer your question without knowing that.